# Group homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/n\Bbb Z$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ must be zero

Tags: group-theory, integers, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I've got to prove that any group homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/n\Bbb Z$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ must be zero, but I cannot seem to do it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Textbook application of [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) is to take $n=2$, try to build a non-trivial homomorphism and see what obstruction there is for you to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the order of an element $m\in(\mathbb Z,+)$ when $m\neq 0$?

Comment: @Juan23 Group homomorphisms need not preserve orders. Not even finite orders. Group monomorphisms do preserve orders.

Comment: Thanks! It was so obvious...

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Indeed. But group homomorphisms always map elements with finite order into elements with finite order.

Comment: Yes, even more is true. The order of the image divides the order of the element if it has finite order.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta why does the order of the image have to divide the order of the element if it has finite order? Also, can you give an example of a group homomorphism that does not preserve order?

Comment: Because of $f: G \to H$ is a group morphism and $g \in G$ has finite order $n$, then $1_H = f(1_G) = f(g^n) = f(g)^n$ and thus the order of $f(g)$ divides $n$, which is the order of $g$. For your second question, consider the trivial map $G \to \{id\}$ where $G$ is any non-trivial group. Then the order of the image of a non-identity element in $G$ is always strictly smaller than the order of the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is any such homomorphism, it is determined by the value of $f(1+n\mathbf Z)$). Now
$$nf(1+n\mathbf Z)=f(n\cdot (1+n\mathbf Z)=f(n\mathbf Z)=0$$
since a homomorphism maps the $0$ element to the $0$ element, and thus, as $\mathbf Z$ has no zero divisors,
$$f(1+n\mathbf Z)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks! I found this alternative proof also helpful